# Pagination of a query in joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, pagination

I've an article in joomla 3 with php code like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM bello ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


echo $row['name']." ".$row['surname']." ".$row['age']."<br/><br/>";
}
```

Now, because this table bello is full of data, I'd like to da a pagination of the result..I've tried to use jquery or php methods but in Joomla it seems don't work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Woah wait a minute. Firstly, `mysql_*` is way passed it sell by date (deprecated) so you should not be using this at all. Secondly, Joomla has it's own database class so please use it: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: thanks...but I didn't find what I looking for in your link..:-(

Comment: It does not solve your issue, but it shows you how to properly connect to the database and write a query. Currently, you could be prone to SQL injections

Comment: In addition to Lodder's very valid security concerns,  your code has no supporting context.  You say the code is in an article, which doesn't make sense.   If you're interacting with the database and wanting to leverage core Joomla features such as pagination,  you should package you're CRUD operations inside a component or module at a minimum.  Is this code inside a custom extension?